# Visual Studio ignoring "Additional Library Directories" field

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors

I have several libraries I need to use but I have been confronted by an unusual error, here is what happens. I create a new project and as always I go into **properties > Linker > Input** to add additional dependencies. I then go into **Linker > General** and include their location under additional library directories.

The problem is that no matter what I do, Visual Studio appears to be ignoring the additional library directories field, despite me seeing it correctly in the command line. As a result I am getting a cannot open lib (LNK1104) error.

Everything works when I put the path alongside the lib and I checked for spelling mistakes. I also tried moving the libs around and providing alternative paths but everything points to visual studio just ignoring that field. What makes this even more bizarre is that I have another project in which everything works just fine.

Does anyone have any insight on why this might be happening?

Comment: Please, be more precise on what libs do you get LNK1104, it may be just because of the ordering of include libs in your file based on confrontations between them?

Comment: The custom ones included in the directory. Built-Ins still work. No, ordering isn't the problem, VS just can't find them despite me adding additional directories.

Comment: Have you gone through all these [possibilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: OK, it may be caused because you made incorrect filename, check if anything suspicious like blank field, š, ć or anything like that is in your filename. Also, make sure that you put your custom libraries after system ones.

Comment: @jjlin: Yes, in fact because adding the full path to the lib fixed the problem I can conclude that none of those issues could affect me. It's only when I add the path to the additional library directories that it doesn't work.

Comment: @DzekTrek: There is nothing weird going on with the filenames. Order wouldn't matter either if it compiles properly when it finds them.

Comment: Have you restarted Visual Studio? I had an issue last week where Visual Studio wouldn't pull in library paths from my property sheets until I restarted Visual Studio, removed the sheets, and then re-added them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so after a good nights sleep I figured out the problem. It turns out that my path, specified by $(SolutionDir), had a comma in it. I feel this is a bug more than anything else because it worked when I added it directly when specifying the lib. Removing the comma from the path leading up to the project directory solved the problem. (And no, adding quotes didn't fix it either).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem exact problem,  I tried the solution above to include header files, restarted VS, however that did not solve the problem.

What I did is changed the **Solutions Configuration** option from *Debug* to *Release* and then Visual Studio miraculously found them.

Comment: This is what actually worked for me but it wasn't magic. I was adding the .LIB dependency in Release build and then was building in Debug mode. Typical mistake, commenting for future reference.

Comment: Worked for me as well.